# How to let tensorflow use cpu and gpu at the same time

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, yolo

I am currently working on a project in which I need to use Keras pickle to detect text then I need to run yolov3 object detection.
I am using Keras according to this [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=y1ZrOs9s2QA&list=LL&index=16). and I am trying to apply Yolov3 using TensorFlow according to the following [tutorial.](https://github.com/theAIGuysCode/Object-Detection-API)

The workflow of code is: first using Keras then yolo, and both of them are separated functions.
So if I  try to run my code on GPU it seems like I can't run the yolo function after running the Keras function, I keep getting this error :

```
     Physical devices cannot be modified after being initialized")
     RuntimeError: Physical devices cannot be modified after being initialized
```

I had searched on the internet about how to force Keras uses Cpu and I found you need to put this line of code

```
import os
os.environ['CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES'] = '-1'
```

before importing Keras but this method makes the whole code using CPU. I also tried to put

```
del os.environ['CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES']
```

before calling the yolo function to make yolo use GPU but it didn't work. the whole code still using CPU
so my question is: is there any method to makes Keras uses CPU then makes yolo uses GPU
or if I can make both Keras and yolo use GPU without getting the previous error. I hope I can explain the problem in the right way.

EDIT :

so first I am calling Keras function

```
def Keras():
pickle_in = open("model_trained.p", "rb")
model = pickle.load(pickle_in)

"""some codes detect text from some image
   and save it in  variable
"""
yolo()
```

then I call yolo function

```
def yolo():
  physical_devices = tf.config.experimental.list_physical_devices('GPU')
  if len(physical_devices) > 0:
    tf.config.experimental.set_memory_growth(physical_devices[0], True)
    yolo = YoloV3(classes=6)

yolo.load_weights('./weights/yolov3.tf')
logging.info('weights loaded')

class_names = [c.strip() for c in open('./data/labels/coco.names').readlines()]
logging.info('classes loaded')

times = []

try:
    vid = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
except:
    vid = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

out = None

fps = 0.0
count = 0
while True:
    _, img = vid.read()

    if img is None:
        logging.warning("Empty Frame")
        time.sleep(0.1)
        count += 1
        if count < 3:
            continue
        else:
            break

    img_in = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
    img_in = tf.expand_dims(img_in, 0)
    img_in = transform_images(img_in, 416)

    t1 = time.time()
    boxes, scores, classes, nums = yolo.predict(img_in)
    fps = (fps + (1. / (time.time() - t1))) / 2

    img = draw_outputs(img, (boxes, scores, classes, nums), class_names)
    img = cv2.putText(img, "FPS: {:.2f}".format(fps), (0, 30),
                      cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_COMPLEX_SMALL, 1, (0, 0, 255), 2)
    cv2.imshow('output', img)
    if cv2.waitKey(1) == ord('q'):
        break

cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

the full traceback of the error

```
File "Desktop\App\yolov3.py", 
line 94, in start yolo = YoloV3(classes=number_of_c)

File "\App\yolov3_tf2\models.py", line 211, in YoloV3     
tf.config.experimental.set_memory_growth(physical_devices[0], True)

File"anaconda3\envs\yolov3gpu\lib\sitepackages\tensorflow_core\python\framework\config.py", line 494,
in set_memory_growth     context.context().set_memory_growth(device, enable)

File "anaconda3\envs\yolov3-gpu\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\eager\context.py", line 1241, in set_memory_growth
```

mirrored_strategy :

```
import os
import tensorflow as tf
os.environ["CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES"]="0,1" 

def Keras():
mirrored_strategy = tf.distribute.MirroredStrategy(devices["/gpu:0","/gpu:1"])
pickle_in = open("model_trained.p", "rb")
with mirrored_strategy.scope():
      model = pickle.load(pickle_in)

  """some codes detect text from some image
 and save it in  variable
 """
```

yolo()

Comment: You need to include the full details, including code, in your question itself.

Comment: I add the code sir

Comment: Remove the first three lines of your yolo() function and try again, I don't think they are needed.

Comment: I tried this before sir and I got the same error in this line of code  yolo = YoloV3(classes=number_of_c)

Comment: Then please add the full traceback of the error

Comment: Add it to the question, not as a comment

Comment: ok sorry about that

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to run whole script on CPU.

You need following code:

```
import os
os.environ["CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES"]="0"
```

If you have more then one GPU, you can use mirrored_strategy:

```
import os
import tensorflow as tf
os.environ["CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES"]="0,1,2,..." #Num of your GPUs

mirrored_strategy = tf.distribute.MirroredStrategy(devices=["/gpu:0", "/gpu:1", ...])
```

And then put your model inside scope:

```
with mirrored_strategy.scope():
    model = Sequential()
    model.add(...)
```

Comment: I have two GPUS in my system (RTX 2070s). I tried your solutions sir and I got this error : 
raise ValueError(handle` is not available outside the replica context
ValueError: `handle` is not available outside the replica context or a tf.distribute.Strategy.update() call.

Comment: Can you show me, your code including mirrored_strategy?